# Exceptions while running Spark job on EMR cluster "java.io.IOException: All datanodes are bad"

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

We have AWS EMR setup to process jobs which are written in Scala. We are able to run the jobs on small dataset, but while running same job on large dataset I get exception "java.io.IOException: All datanodes are bad."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting spark.shuffle.service.enabled to true resolved this issue for me.

The default configuration of AWS EMR has set *spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled* to true, but *spark.shuffle.service.enabled* is set to *false*.

*spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled* allows Spark to assign the executors dynamically to different task. The *spark.shuffle.service.enabled* when set to *false* disables the external shuffle service and data is stored only on executors. When the executors is reassigned the data is lost and the exception "java.io.IOException: All datanodes are bad." is thrown for data request.

Comment: It is enabled in my cluster, but I still see the same issue from time to time.